# Redirect a Wordpress site to a non wordpress site with a different domain name and hosted in a different server

Tags: redirects

I have my old Wordpress site .
Now I have developed a new custom HTML site to  and hosted it in another server with a different domain name. All the pages in the existing site is present in the new site as well.

So, now I want the users accessing my old word press site to get redirected to the new HTML site (non word press site).

Any advise if I can do a 301 redirect from a WP site to a non wordpress site- new domain & hosted in another server? If not possible is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Is there any reason why you think you can't do a 301 redirect here? Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes ; tried it by editing the .htaccess file. Didn't work. I have added the below statements                                                                                         RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com [NC,OR] RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com [NC] RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

Comment: I have tried by appending the existing lines with the above lines and also tried by deleting existing lines and keeping only the above lines in the htaccess fle. Eitherway it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do so without affecting the SEO, what you have to do is:

Set 301 redirection rules in your old sites .htaccess file
If you've exact pages on new domain then you should have to 301 redirect those page to new domain page to pass SEO equity.

Your code has one mistake add "**http://**" before your new domain, then recheck or you can follow below methods.

```
Method 1:
Options +FollowSymlinks 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

Method 2:
Options +FollowSymlinks 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \olddomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Method 3:
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Method 4:
Redirect 301 / http://www.newdomain.com/
```

Usually all above methods works fine, however it depends on your implementation as well, debug your code and check for the common conflicts

You can refer this question for more information on this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945568/htaccess-redirect-all-pages-to-new-domain

Comment: Thank you very much . Home page is redirected now when I change my code from Https to Http. 2 of the pages in old site is not having the same file name in the new site. eg. it has  www.oldsite.com/page1/ in the Wordpress site . The same is given as  www.newsite.com/name1.html.  How do I handle this ?

Comment: How many such pages are there?
If they're less than 50 then you should redirect them to newer version this will not harm the SEO thing as anyone can reach to your new URL from old URL, you got saved, you can do this similarly in your .htaccess file

Comment: Thanks again. I have now managed to redirect all the files from olddomain to the new domain root with the following statements .                           RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite.com$ [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.oldsite.com$  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newsite.com/ [R=301,L]                                               The issue is  it is redirecting the admin page as well. How do I exclude the oldsite.com/admin   or oldsite.com/wp-admin/admin.php from this redirect ?

Comment: I have used the below statements to exclude the redirect of wp-admin and wp-login.php .                            
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.oldsite.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)?wp-login\.php(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)?wp-admin$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newsite.com/ [R=301,L]                                                It is still redirecting the  oldsite.com/wp-admin/ and oldsite..com/wp-login.php to the new domain.  Any advise on how to correct it ?